# XPath with custom value for operand instead of xml

Tags: java, xpath

Is there is possibility of perform xpath eval with custom value instead of having xml.

Example:

```
count(/departmemt/employees) > 10
```

Here, i will provide the values for /department/employee and i want to use xpath libraray in java to take care of doing the evaluation.

It is something like the user exposed method, `String getValue (String operand)...`

here getValue method should get called from xpathEngine and i will take care of providing the value for each operand.

Please help me if there is any possibility of doing this.

Thanks
Durai

Comment: Do you mean that you want to evaluate an XPath expression in which the names of the elements are supplied at run time?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you're asking for. If you can show some more detailed examples of each component, that may help.

Answer (score 0):

For use XPath-like structures in java can be used commons-jxpath

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jxpath/

Comment: Thanks for your comments. basically the structure of my object is bit different .. it is kind of DOM node.. each parent and child will intern refer to the same structure.. for the apache-common expetation is like Department-> list of employee but here that is not the case... each thing will be like DataNode.. getParent of DataNode is again one more DataNode object..